# Как обновить вложенный в объект массив? MongoDB / Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Есть такой документ:

```
{
_id: '5fabb772180ceee41540e603',
data: {
    arr: ['1', '2', '3']
}
```

}

Не могу понять как мне добраться до конкретного поля! Мне нужно поменять в массиве `arr` значение 2 на 5. Но как добраться до этого конкретного поля и заменить значение!?

Comment: способы могут быть разные. Зависит от ситуации. Читайте здесь - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

Comment: Как раз читаю эту доку но начинаю писать код и, видно что то я недопонимаю.  Буду благодарен за пример кода.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Пример кода ниже.

```
       const data = await Test.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                _id: '5fabb772180ceee41540e603',
                "data.description": "2"
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    "data.description.$": 'someValue'
                }
            },
            {
                new: true
            }
        )
```